A dark animated movie about an orphaned girl working in an oppressive factory
I’m searching for a movie with the following details:

Main character: A young girl whose parents are dead. She works at a factory run by an evil woman who exploits the children working there.
Factory: The factory is a dark, oppressive place where the children work. The evil woman is aggressive towards them, and one of the children tries to eat something that goes through the pipes, leading to two large men in black taking him away.
Beginning: The movie starts in a countryside setting, with fields and forests. Later, the setting shifts mostly to the factory.
Animation style: The film is likely 2D animation, or possibly stop-motion, but it seems more like 2D.
Time period: The film seems to take place in a poor, possibly historical setting, around the 1930s or 1940s. I watched it in 2013-2015. I saw it on Swedish TV channels. It’s probably made in 1990-2000.
Key scene: The girl is shown standing in front of her parents’ grave before being taken away to the factory.
Tone and atmosphere: The atmosphere is dark, and the movie has a somewhat tragic or dystopian feel, with the exploitation of children and a harsh environment.

But I’m not quite sure.

Those are some great details, but the following would also be helpful: When did you watch this? And was it in a cinema or on TV? Do you think you could take a guess on when you think it might have been made?

A bit of a stretch, but Madeline the animated feature with Jason Alexander as the villain?

I watched it in 2013-2015 i saw it on Swedish TV channels it’s probably made in 1990-2000

Is it Trick or Treaters (2007)? Also known as The Three Robbers.
It is based on a German book The Three Robbers
A recently orphaned girl is being sent to her aunt's orphanage. She is "kidnapped" by a gang of highwaymen but manages to escape, and continues to the orphanage which she discovers is a factory relying on forced child labour. With the help of the robbers (who turn out to have been orphans), she helps free the orphans.
